# Grabbing sublevel elements xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery

I Have an XML conaining  elemens as beeing an shipment and  elements as beeein cargo-lines of that shipping.

In 1 file are multiple  elements with 1 or more  elements.

I need to create an XML file in another format.

Needed format:

```sql
<shipment>
--shipment lines
<cargo>
--cargo line
</cargo>
<cargo>
--cargo line
</cargo>
<cargo>
--cargo line
</cargo>
</shipment>
<shipment>
--shipment lines
<cargo>
--cargo line
</cargo>
</shipment>
```

Current SQL:

```sql
set @shipmentsXML = (SELECT     
            "customer_id" = T.c.query('./ediCustomerNumber').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
            "reference" = T.c.query('./ediReference').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),


(select

                "unitamount" = T.C.query('./quantity').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
                "weight" = T.c.query('./grossWeight').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
                "loadingmeter" = T.c.query('./loadingMeters').value('.', 'varchar(50)')

                FROM @Xml.nodes('./file/goodsLine') T(c)
                FOR XML PATH ('cargo'), TYPE)


FROM @Xml.nodes('manifest-out/consol') T(c)
FOR XML PATH ('shipment')
)
```

working with the console tags, but no cargo line is showing

source XML:

```xml
<manifest-out type="tag">
  <ediCustomerNumber>*******</ediCustomerNumber>
  <ediCustomerDepartment>Ic</ediCustomerDepartment>
  <transmitter>R</transmitter>
  <receiver>*******</receiver>
  <ediReference>*******</ediReference>
  <referenceIndication>0</referenceIndication>
  <internalShipmentNumber>*******</internalShipmentNumber>
  <ediFunction1>6</ediFunction1>
  <dateTimeZone>2019-07-24T13:05:55+02:00</dateTimeZone>
  <fileHeader type="tag">
  </fileHeader>
  <consol type="tag">
    <file type="tag">
      <operationalPeriod>2019/07</operationalPeriod>
      <loadingDate>2019-07-17</loadingDate>
      <loadingTime>00:00:00</loadingTime>
      <unloadingDate>2019-07-26</unloadingDate>
      <unloadingTime>17:00:00</unloadingTime>
      <primaryReference>8017883827</primaryReference>
      <deliveryTerm>DAP</deliveryTerm>
      <codeShedHandling>true</codeShedHandling>
      <goodsLine type="tag">
        <quantity>3.000</quantity>
        <grossWeight>415.000</grossWeight>
        <loadingMeters>1.633</loadingMeters>
      </goodsLine>
      <goodsLine type="tag">
        <quantity>1.000</quantity>
        <grossWeight>605.000</grossWeight>
        <loadingMeters>4.633</loadingMeters>
      </goodsLine>
      <goodsLine type="tag">
        <quantity>2.000</quantity>
        <grossWeight>75.000</grossWeight>
        <loadingMeters>2.633</loadingMeters>
      </goodsLine>
    </file>
  </consol>
  <consol type="tag">
    <file type="tag">
      <operationalPeriod>2019/07</operationalPeriod>
      <loadingDate>2019-07-17</loadingDate>
      <loadingTime>00:00:00</loadingTime>
      <unloadingDate>2019-07-26</unloadingDate>
      <unloadingTime>17:00:00</unloadingTime>
      <primaryReference>8017883827</primaryReference>
      <deliveryTerm>DAP</deliveryTerm>
      <codeShedHandling>true</codeShedHandling>
      <goodsLine type="tag">
        <quantity>3.000</quantity>
        <grossWeight>415.000</grossWeight>
        <loadingMeters>1.633</loadingMeters>
      </goodsLine>
    </file>
  </consol>
</manifest-out>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on selecting the goodlines

Comment: One hint: I'd avoid using the same aliases (in your case `T(c)`) for the inner and the outer `.nodes()`. I prefer using `A(speakingSomething)` and `B(SomeOther)` to get them separated and unambigous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```xml
SELECT g2.value('(/manifest-out/ediCustomerNumber/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS customer_id 
      ,g2.value('(/manifest-out/ediReference/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS reference
      ,(
        SELECT gl.value('(quantity/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS unitamount
              ,gl.value('(grossWeight/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS [weight]
              ,gl.value('(loadingMeters/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS loadingmeter
        FROM g2.nodes('./file/goodsLine') A(gl)
        FOR XML PATH('cargo'),TYPE
       ) 
FROM @xml.nodes('/manifest-out/consol') B(g2)
FOR XML PATH('shipment');
```

thnx for the help and suggestions, they help me finding the sollution!

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, if this is really the correct approach... You are using `.nodes()` to achieve `B.g2` from the XPath `/manifest-out/consol`. but you are using `g2.value()` starting again from the root node. This solution looks very close to my suggestion actually (just a bit wrong ;-) ). However: Writing your own answer and writing *thx for the help* is kind, but nobody will see this. In future please write below the answers to address your helpers and one more hint: The SO-way to say *Thx* is a vote and/or the acceptance of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the expected output, at least, it is not clear to me... But I hope I guessed this correctly:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/manifest-out/ediCustomerNumber/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS customer_id 
      ,@xml.value('(/manifest-out/ediReference/text())[1]','varchar(50)') AS reference
      ,(
        SELECT gl.value('(quantity/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS unitamount
              ,gl.value('(grossWeight/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS [weight]
              ,gl.value('(loadingMeters/text())[1]','decimal(14,10)') AS loadingmeter
        FROM @xml.nodes('/manifest-out/consol/file/goodsLine') A(gl)
        FOR XML PATH('cargo'),TYPE
       ) 
FOR XML PATH('shipment');
```

The result

```
<shipment>
  <customer_id>*******</customer_id>
  <reference>*******</reference>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>3.0000000000</unitamount>
    <weight>415.0000000000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>1.6330000000</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>1.0000000000</unitamount>
    <weight>605.0000000000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>4.6330000000</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>2.0000000000</unitamount>
    <weight>75.0000000000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>2.6330000000</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
</shipment>
```

The idea in short:

We can pick the `1:1` related values (your *shipment data*) directly from the XML and return it within `<shipment>`.
The nested `SELECT` will pick the repeating elements below `<goodsLine>` and return each of them within `<cargo>`.

Btw: Your own code was very, very close...

It would work if you either change your inner XPath to `/manifest-out/consol/file/goodsLine` or if you use `T.c.nodes()`. You are trying to use the *relative path* `./file/goodsLine` against the *source XML*. You might even go the *deep search route* with `FROM @xml.nodes('//goodsLine') T(c)`, but the general advise is: Be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

XQuery FLWOR expression is the best way to re-shape XML. There is no need to convert (1) XML data type into relational data, and after that (2) back to XML.
Check it out.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<manifest-out type="tag">
    <ediCustomerNumber>*******</ediCustomerNumber>
    <ediCustomerDepartment>Ic</ediCustomerDepartment>
    <transmitter>R</transmitter>
    <receiver>*******</receiver>
    <ediReference>*******</ediReference>
    <referenceIndication>0</referenceIndication>
    <internalShipmentNumber>*******</internalShipmentNumber>
    <ediFunction1>6</ediFunction1>
    <dateTimeZone>2019-07-24T13:05:55+02:00</dateTimeZone>
    <fileHeader type="tag">
    </fileHeader>
    <consol type="tag">
        <file type="tag">
            <operationalPeriod>2019/07</operationalPeriod>
            <loadingDate>2019-07-17</loadingDate>
            <loadingTime>00:00:00</loadingTime>
            <unloadingDate>2019-07-26</unloadingDate>
            <unloadingTime>17:00:00</unloadingTime>
            <primaryReference>8017883827</primaryReference>
            <deliveryTerm>DAP</deliveryTerm>
            <codeShedHandling>true</codeShedHandling>
            <goodsLine type="tag">
                <quantity>3.000</quantity>
                <grossWeight>415.000</grossWeight>
                <loadingMeters>1.633</loadingMeters>
            </goodsLine>
            <goodsLine type="tag">
                <quantity>1.000</quantity>
                <grossWeight>605.000</grossWeight>
                <loadingMeters>4.633</loadingMeters>
            </goodsLine>
            <goodsLine type="tag">
                <quantity>2.000</quantity>
                <grossWeight>75.000</grossWeight>
                <loadingMeters>2.633</loadingMeters>
            </goodsLine>
        </file>
    </consol>
</manifest-out>';

SELECT @xml.query('<shipment>
<customerID>{data(/manifest-out/ediCustomerNumber)}</customerID>
<CustomerDepartment>{data(/manifest-out/ediCustomerDepartment)}</CustomerDepartment>
{
for $x in /manifest-out/consol/file/goodsLine
return <cargo>
   <unitamount>{data($x/quantity)}</unitamount>
   <weight>{data($x/grossWeight)}</weight>
   <loadingmeter>{data($x/loadingMeters)}</loadingmeter>
 </cargo>
}
</shipment>');
```

Output XML:

```
<shipment>
  <customerID>*******</customerID>
  <CustomerDepartment>Ic</CustomerDepartment>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>3.000</unitamount>
    <weight>415.000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>1.633</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>1.000</unitamount>
    <weight>605.000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>4.633</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
  <cargo>
    <unitamount>2.000</unitamount>
    <weight>75.000</weight>
    <loadingmeter>2.633</loadingmeter>
  </cargo>
</shipment>
```

Comment: The problem is getting only the goodline(s) from the parent consol tag, now i get all goodlines in 1 shipment.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned earlier there is no need (1) to convert XML data type into relational data, (2) CAST values into particular SQL Server data types, and after that (3) convert back to XML.
Here is an updated SQL with XQuery based on the refined requirements.

```
SELECT @xml.query('<root>
{
for $x in /manifest-out/consol
return <shipment>
    <customerID>{data(/manifest-out/ediCustomerNumber)}</customerID>
    <CustomerDepartment>{data(/manifest-out/ediCustomerDepartment)}</CustomerDepartment>
    {
        for $c in $x/file/goodsLine
            return <cargo>
                    <unitamount>{data($c/quantity)}</unitamount>
                    <weight>{data($c/grossWeight)}</weight>
                    <loadingmeter>{data($c/loadingMeters)}</loadingmeter>
                </cargo>
    }
</shipment>
}
</root>');
```